# Create a html element with attribute has the same value with its text using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to create a HTML element like this:

```
<option value="Replaced">by this</option>
```

For example:

```
<option value="ThisIsTest">ThisIsTest</option>
```

**EDIT**

And I have to use jQuery, something like this, with value="ThisIsTest":

```
$("button").click(function(value) {
   $("#number").append("<option value=\"" + value + "\">" + value + "</option>");
});
```

But it always returns a HTML like this:

```
<option value="value">ThisIsTest</option>
```

I tried with `&quot;` as well, but it also didn't work.

Comment: This is a bit confusing. Why would you want to append an option to a paragraph? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @LucasRodrigues: Sorry to confuse you. I don't want to append an option to a paragraph. This is just pseudocode, maybe a bad one :)

Comment: Are you trying to replace `value` with `innerText`?

Comment: I think the `value` in this context is the `event` and not the text of the `option`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If not sure if that what you looking for but if you want to pass value from the button to the event you can use data attributes **[data()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/)**, check example bellow.

Hope this helps.

---

### Snippet

```js
$("button").click(function() {
    var button_value = $(this).data('value');
  
    $("select").append("<option value='" + button_value + "'>" + button_value + "</option>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button data-value='1'>Add option 1</button>
<br/>
<button data-value='2'>Add option 2</button>
<br/>
<button data-value='3'>Add option 3</button>
<br/>
<select></select>
```

Comment: Thanks, I am gonna try and let you know. Like I answered above, my example is just pseudocode, a bad one. I don't intend to append an option to a paragraph :)

Comment: @LouisT I'm just noticing that you're trying to pass value to the click event, you can't do it by this way, you have to use data attributes.. check my update.

Comment: You're right, I should have gotten value first. Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why that piece of code wouldn't be working, but if you omit the value attribute, the default value will be the display text.

> The content of this attribute represents the value to be submitted with the form, should this option be selected. If this attribute is omitted, the value is taken from the text content of the option element.
>   [Mozilla Option](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option)